# how can I find this matlab function named "svmpredict.m"

Tags: matlab

I am studying image quilty ，　a algorithm named "divine" which is from paper "Blind Image Quality Assessment: From Natural Scene Statistics to Perceptual Quality" , this algorithm used
a toolbox matlabPyrTools (I have downloaded), and another function svmpredict.m, I　cannot find it in its sourcecode(the soucecode page is  http://live.ece.utexas.edu/research/quality/DIIVINE_release.zip) .

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it's likely to be from [LibSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), a freely available package for support vector machines that includes a MATLAB wrapper.

Comment: Thank you very much ! it is from libsvm (the matlab version )

Comment: Great! If you accept the answer, others will find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

`svmpredict` is NO official matlab function so use a search engine to look for it or ask the author of the toolbox where to find it, e.g. https://www.google.de/#hl=de&q=svmpredict%20matlab&fp=1&cad=b&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb

Comment: Thank you ! it is from libsvm (the matlab version ).